# What's happened to fb_sig_page_id

Tags: facebook

Our Facebook app relies on the GET variable supplied by Facebook.  We use fb_sig_page_id in particular.

This seems to have suddenly stopped coming through and I can't find anything online about it.  Did I miss the memo?  Does anyone know what's happened here?

Comment: You got Zuckerpunched! I think they deprecated that parameter a while back. It's using signed_request now.

Comment: Yep, we obviously missed the memo here.  I've just done some emergency surgery to bring it back to life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an old FBML app you're asking about?

I can't find anything in the current documentation discussing this parameter - the current method of making page tab apps (all new apps since March 2011 + many before that) uses a POST request to your app which contains a [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) from which you can determine the page ID

Heads-up that FBML is totally deprecated since January and scheduled for removal in June 2012, so it may be better to reimplement using the current APIs rather than trying to work around this specific issue